# Bizarre SQL bug IIS 7

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, iis-7

I have recently had to amend the following SQL to this:

```
$this->db->select('StaffMembers.Id AS StaffMembers_Id, Contacts.AssociatedStaffMember_Id');
$this->db->join("StaffMembers", "Contacts.AssociatedStaffMember_Id=StaffMembers.Id");                   
$q1 = $this->db->get_where($this->contacts_table, 'Contacts.AssociatedStaffMember_Id ='.$ContactId);
$s = $q1->row_array();
```

YET when I log in,it displays an old SQL:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number:

Invalid column name 'Contact_Id'.

SELECT Contacts.Id, StaffMembers.Id AS StaffMember_Id 
FROM StaffMembers JOIN Contacts ON Contacts.Id=StaffMembers.Contact_Id 
WHERE Contacts.Id =161
```

I have restarted mssql server, flushed memcached and iis7, but it is still showing the old query. No idea, why on earth it is doing this, any thoughts?

Found the problem, there seemed to be some duplicate SQL in a controller class (when there shouldn't be!)

Fixed that - problem was resolved. Cheers.

Comment: Are you using some sort of query caching mechanism in CodeIgniter? [CI Database Caching](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html)

Comment: Nope not that I am aware off, is there a quick way of checking?

Comment: Look in the config file (application/config/database.php) for the line setting the value for `$db['default']['cache_on']`.  Be sure to check your application's config file if you aren't just using the default.

Comment: It's set to false: $db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

Comment: You could try adding `$this->db->flush_cache();` before you begin your select statement, to confirm that it is/isn't the cache.

Comment: No luck - I wonder if it is replication that is causing this, those new columns 'Contacts.AssociatedStaffMember_Id' are after the msrepl field.

Comment: Are you able to restart IIS to see if it's a server caching problem in SQLServer?

Answer (score 0):

Does this resolve the issue in any way?

```
$this->db->select('StaffMembers.Id AS StaffMembers_Id, Contacts.AssociatedStaffMember_Id');
$this->db->join("StaffMembers", "Contacts.AssociatedStaffMember_Id=StaffMembers.Id");  
$this->db->where('Contacts.AssociatedStaffMember_Id', $ContactId);
$q1 = $this->db->get($this->contacts_table);
$s = $q1->row_array();
```

Your previous code was using get_where and I'm not 100% sure if that can be mixed.

Do you have an underlying class that manipulates the `$this->db` class before you run this code?

Gav

Comment: Solved the problem, there seemed to have been some SQL code in a controller that was causing problems. Had to remove it.